# Save Bing Daily Photo Image for website background

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to grab the url of the img in the XML file of the daily bing photo so i can set it as the src of my websites background.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

<script>
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET", "http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=xml&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US", true);
    x.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
            var doc = x.responseXML;
            var stock = document.getElementById("stock");
            var img = doc.getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            stocksrc.setAttribute("src", img);
        }
    };
    x.send(null);
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <img id="stock" src="#">
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error im having:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=xml&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do XHR requests from one domain (abc.com) to another (xyz.com) unless the xyz.com explicitly allows abc.com to do so.

As bing.com have not explicitly allowed you to do cross domain requests (ie, they have not included the appropriate `Access-control-allow-origin` header), browsers will prevent you from loading that resource from your own website.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/260035 for more

Comment: How would i then access the url tag inside the XML through the iframe?

Comment: From the browser, you can't. Not directly. You would have to go via some sort of server proxy.